# photoshop script place one text after another

Tags: javascript, paragraph, photoshop-script

I am trying to place one text from array after another in PSD using photoshop script. Problem is that it could be not obvious if first text fit into one line or not, because I have to place second text right after N pixels after first one. And if there will be 2 lines in the title, I'm screwed.

Is there any chance to have a dynamic paragraph height, or count lines in the paragraph? Or how can I solve this problem?

Here is my code:

```
function createTexts() {
    createText(250, 100, 110, titles[count_psd-1], 1);
    createText(200, 50, 250, descriptions[count_psd-1], 0);

    saveImage();
}

function createText(h, fontSize, hPosition, content, light) {
    var doc = app.activeDocument;
    var TextLayer = doc.artLayers.add();
    TextLayer.kind = LayerKind.TEXT;
    var txtRef = TextLayer.textItem;
    txtRef.kind = TextType.PARAGRAPHTEXT;
    txtRef.antiAliasMethod = AntiAlias.SMOOTH;
    txtRef.width = 1050;
    txtRef.height = h;
    if (lang==0) {
        if (light==1){
            txtRef.font = "HelveticaNeue-UltraLight";
        } else {
            txtRef.font = "HelveticaNeue";
        }
    } else {
        txtRef.font = "MicrosoftSansSerif";
    }
    txtRef.contents = content;
    txtRef.size = fontSize;
    var textPosition = [75,hPosition];
    txtRef.position = textPosition;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: I know nothing about photoshop script, but if I was doing this the first idea I would try is to not manually set the height with `txtRef.height = h;` and see if it auto sets the height after the content is added. Might be worth a try?

Comment: Yeah, I've tried this. But unfortunately if you don't set the height of the paragraph, it considers as 0, and no text is displayed. Thanks for the tip though!

Answer (score 0):

I've run into this before and the best I was able to do was set my paragraph much larger than required to display the text and rasterize a copy of the text layer.  Then I calculated the required height from the rasterized layer to apply back to the text layer. Finally I deleted the rasterized copy.  A painful workaround but it did work.